# MongoDB structure: single collection vs multiple smaller collections

Tags: mongodb, database-design

I have a general database structure question.  In my scenario I happen to be using mongodb.

I'm creating an application where a user can upload a list of songs (title, artist, etc.) but am not sure if I should have one songList collection for all users or a separate songList.user# collection for each individual user.  The users can only ever query songs associated to them so user A will NEVER know about user B's songs.

**Code Examples:**

***Multiple collections per user***

```
db.songList.userA.find()
{"title": "Some song of user A", "artist": "Some artist of user A"}

db.songList.userB.find()
{"title": "Some song of user B", "artist": "Some artist of user B"}
```

- Pros

  - Smaller collection size to query
- Cons

  - Maintainability

    - 1,000 users means 1,000 collections

***vs single collection with an owning 'user' field***

```
db.songList.find({"user":"A"})
{"title": "Some song of user A", "artist": "Some artist of user A", "user": "A"}
```

- Pros

  - Flexibility to query across users if need ever arised
- Cons

  - Performance

I'm trying to build a pro/con list but still on the fence.  Given that each user's songs are going to be isolated from each other which approach is better?  My main concern is maintenance and query performance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of worrying about things like this, build *something*.  You'll probably find out what'll work best by building it, instead of worrying about details.

Comment: Agree with @SomeKittens. That said, I'd do it per user because it's easier to make a mistake and show A's songs to B. Anyway, I'd worry about optimization if/when I had enough users.

Comment: Security-wise, having one collection per user makes it possible to use Mongodb's collection-level access control mechanisms. This way, it can be ensured at the database level that one user never accesses another's data.

Comment: @Steven I am curious to know which design you went with as I am also facing a similar dilemma at the moment.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would recommend `NOT` to make separate collection per user.

Read the [documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Using+a+Large+Number+of+Collections)

> By default MongoDB has a limit of approximately 24,000 namespaces per
>   database. Each namespace is 628 bytes, the .ns file is 16MB by
>   default.
>
> Each collection counts as a namespace, as does each index.  Thus if
>   every collection had one index, we can create up to 12,000
>   collections.  The --nssize parameter allows you to increase this limit
>   (see below).
>
> Be aware that there is a certain minimum overhead per collection -- a
>   few KB.  Further, any index will require at least 8KB of data space as
>   the b-tree page size is 8KB. Certain operations can get slow if there
>   are a lot of collections and the meta data gets paged out.

So you won't be able to gracefully handle it if your users exceed the namespace limit. Also it won't be high on performance with the growth of your userbase.

**UPDATE**

As @Henry Liu mentioned in the comments. For Mongodb 3.0 or above using WiredTiger storage engine, it will no longer be the limit.

[docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#namespaces](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#namespaces)

Comment: Thanks for the info but reading the next paragraph describes how --nssize can be used to up this limit (Maximum .ns file size is 2GB).  So if every songList collection has only 1 index I can theoretically have 240,000+ collections before approaching 2GB. (This limit is almost cut in half if I were to have 2 indexes per collection).

Comment: You can obviously model any way you want to. All I did was recommended a graceful approach :)

Comment: Thanks your input was very helpful, after reading this info multiple collection doesn't seem necessary as I can do what I need in a single collection while avoiding namespace limits.

Comment: As of mongodb 3.0 or above and if you use WiredTiger storage engine, it will no longer be the limit.  https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#namespaces

Comment: Thanks @HenryLiu I wrote the answer way back in 2012. Thanks for updating the information. I have added the update in my answer.

Answer (score 9):

MongoDB is great at scaling horizontally. It can shard a collection across a dynamic cluster to produce a fast, querable collection of your data.

So having a smaller collection size is not really a pro and I am not sure where this theory comes that it is, it isn't in SQL and it isn't in MongoDB. The performance of sharding, if done well, should be relative to the performance of querying a single small collection of data (with a small overhead). If it isn't then you have setup your sharding wrong.

MongoDB is not great at scaling vertically, as @Sushant quoted, the ns size of MongoDB would be a serious limitation here. One thing that quote does not mention is that index size and count also effect the ns size hence why it describes that:

> Thus if every collection had one index, we can create up to 12,000 collections. The --nssize parameter allows you to increase this limit (see below).

Comment: I had read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11514781/mongodb-performance-issue-single-huge-collection-vs-multiple-small-collections) which led me to believe I would see a significant performance gain with multiple smaller collections.  Are you saying if I were to have one collection with a shard key on the user field I should see a similar performance gain?

Comment: There are too many unknowns there to say exactly why he was getting those times, query times are so dependant upon hardware, indexes, data, normalisation etc. However he does note that the query was fast when he had a huge number of records, the problem was when he was using a small number of selectivity within his index (low number of type records with price > 100) which leads me to believe his index was not that good for his query.

Comment: Yes, a shard key on something like user_id (a little bit of guessing here, you should really really reallllllly research this for your data) would produce a decent return for queries containing a user_id. However that is not the full picture with sharding and I would strongely recommend you do some searching on here and google before instantly thinking that user_id will solve your sharding problems.

Comment: Thanks your input was very helpful, if I need to optimize query performance after implementing the single collection I'll do more research and play around with shards.